# Is it possible to name the arguments of a command in the editor interface?

Tags: texstudio, editors

This question isn't related to TeX directly, but I was thinking about it as a total TeX newbie in the past and it still seems an interesting thought experiment. I suppose that the answer depends on which editor one uses, so I'll mention that I'm using TeXStudio.

Suppose I have defined a new command with `\newcommand{\add}[2]{#1} {#2}}`. When one enters the command, the interface displays `\add{arg1}{arg2}` and one is supposed to fill in `arg1` and `arg2`. Is it possible to change these argument placeholders into a custom value in order to make it easier for users to understand what they're supposed to enter? For example, something like `\add{entity}{title}`.

Comment: Not a real answer since you're talking about TeXstudio, but for what is worth, AUCTeX does this by default.  When you insert a supported macro or environment, you're prompted for arguments and the prompt message verbosely indicates what that argument should be.  You don't have to change anything on your side.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about TeXStudio, but you can achieve this in Texmaker:

User->Customize Completion:

[image: Customize Completion dialog box]

The `@` symbol inserts `•` which serves as a tab stop. Use in the editor:

[image: suggested commands]

The downside is that it inserts this text, so you 'll have to delete it to enter your arguments:

[image: use in editor]

Answer (score 1):

To give a name to an command argument in TeXstudio, you have define that command in a cwl file.

For details, see the [FAQ: How does TXS know about valid commands](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#how-does-txs-know-about-valid-commands) and the [definition of the CWL format in the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION).